# When is it a good idea to use Type Gems on Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

So these Gem items, they give a one-time 50% boost to a specific type of attack. After that... well, it's gone forever. It's like your attack is nerfed, just like those moves that lower your stat after use (Leaf Storm, etc.), except these moves can have their effect removed just by switching out.

So far I have only seen two uses that I consider "good": Acrobatics/Flying Gem, and Explosion/Normal Gem.

What other good uses are there for these Gems? Surely there are better items, such as Expert Belt that gives a 20% boost to supereffective moves.

Answer (score 1):

Type gems are more commonly seen in battles in the Battle Whatever or against other people, where used items are returned at the end of the match. They're a lot more useful when they're once per battle rather than once ever.

In this case, they are used for when you really need one move to deal a lot of damage (often to one-shot something annoying). They actually combo quite nicely with the Leaf Storm style moves- you can up the already massive damage of that one attack.

Comment: They're also extremely good for Pokemon who gain bonuses by losing their held item, like Drifblim with Unburden.